# Un-Known Crafting Recipe?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I am currently trying to get my hands on the new huntsman reskin. I decided that I would do a Sniper random primary weapon craft to try and get one. But, when I go to the page and insert the ingredients (1 Scrap + Class Token + Slot Token), it says un-known recipe. How do I fix this? I have used it before to craft Three Rune Blades and Mauls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that it's a Sniper class token, a primary slot token and a scrap metal in the crafting menu and retry. If it doesn't work, try restarting TF2 and recrafting. If not, submit a ticket to Valve support.

Comment: I am using the pre-set recipe, not the custom one. Also, I have tried restarting.

Comment: Try the custom one as well as the pre-set one.

Comment: I tried both. They started working after waiting while.